# Number of elements in orbits is a divisor of $|G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite group acting on a set $X$. Prove that the number of elements in any of the orbits is a divisor of $|G|$.

By definition, the $G$-orbit of $x\in X$ in $X$ is the set:
$$G(x)=\{g \cdot x \in  X : g\in G\}$$

How may I prove this? I have tried to define a mapping from $G$ to $G(x)$ for arbitrary $x$ ($\phi(g)=g \cdot x$) and try to prove it is a bijection, but I can only prove that the map is surjective. So I think this approach may be wrong.

Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially the [orbit-stabilizer lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem).

The following map is surjective: $$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}G&\rightarrow&G(x)\\g&\rightarrow&g\cdot x\end{array}\right.$$
and one has: $$g\cdot x=g'\cdot x\Leftrightarrow g^{-1}g'\in\textrm{Stab}(x).$$
Hence, one has a bijective mapping from $G/\textrm{Stab}(x)$ to $G(x)$ and  they therefore have the same cardinality. To conclude, $\textrm{Stab}(x)$ is a subgroup of $G$ and using [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)) $[G:\textrm{Stab}(x)]$ divides $|G|$.